# QWidget error in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, qwidget

I have the following code in PyCharm.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtGui.QWidget()
w.show()
status = app.exec_()
sys.exit(status)
```

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to run this code.

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Heydar/aaaa.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Heydar/aaaa.py", line 5, in <module>
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QWidget'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help please?

PyCharm is not recognizing QWidget() for some reason

Answer (score 0):

PyQt4 and PyQt5 have different implementations. You are getting this error because it is:

```
QtWidgets.QWidget()
```

According to the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#qtgui-module):

> PyQt4’s QtGui module has been split into PyQt5’s QtGui, QtPrintSupport
>   and QtWidgets modules.

You can see more on this subject [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qwidget.html).